# Gd installed, but "Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()"

Tags: php, gd

Looks like my hosting has gd support, but i still get an error ( PHP Version 5.3.28 )

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()
```

Here is my phpinfo:

```
gd

GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.2.44
WBMP Support    enabled
XBM Support enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning  0   0
```

Comment: If it's enabled, may be you should contact your host provider. Or you can post a snippet where you are using this function.

Comment: gif enabled, png enabled, wmbp and xmb enabled. nothing about jpg, try `imagecreatefromgif`. Also, talking to the hosting provider will most likely give you "correct" answers

Comment: doesn't gd.jpeg_ignore_warning  line means that i have jpeg support ?

Comment: No, it does not mean that you have jpeg support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that while GD is indeed supported that it was *not* compiled with libjpeg.  The gd.jpeg_ignore_warning does *not* mean that you have jpeg support.  If this is your own server make sure to run configure with `--with-jpeg-dir`.  You may have to search for it.  I used the command `find / -name libjpeg*` and got `/usr/lib` for CentOS5.  If this a shared host have them install it for you.

My complete compilation of PHP is as follows:

```
wget http://us1.php.net/distributions/php-5.5.10.tar.gz -O php.tar.gz 
tar -xvf php.tar.gz
cd php-5.5.10
yum -y install libxml2-devel libmcrypt-devel libpng-devel
./configure --with-config-file-path=/etc --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d  --with-apxs2 --with-mysql --with-mysqli --with-zlib --with-curl --with-libdir=lib --with-openssl --with-pdo-mysql --with-mcrypt  --with-pcre-regex --enable-zip --with-gd --enable-mbstring --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib
make clean
make 
make install
```